# How to get node-esl data outside of the connection object?

Tags: sockets, events, freeswitch

I have tried and implemented the esl part for freeswitch using [this](https://github.com/englercj/node-esl/tree/master).

It works fine just that I want the data outside of the connection object and I cannot get it.

This is the code:

```
connection.on('esl::ready', () => {
      connection.api('status', (res: any) => {
        console.log(res.getBody());
        res.getBody();
      });
    });
```

I want this response outside so that I can send it to the controller to display the output in the swagger.

I tried to return the value and store it in variable and print it but could not get it outside.